# How do I Swap a set of FK's in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to swap 1 set of number with another set of numbers.

```
y          z         pk       x
------     ------    ------   -----
1           2         1        5
1           3         2        5
1           4         3        5
5           6         4        5
5           7         5        5
5           8         6        5
1           2         7        9
1           3         8        9
5           6         9        9
1           4         10       9
5           7         11       9
5           8         12       9
```

I need all 1's to be 5's and all 5's to be 1's in column y where x = 9.
y and z fields have FK constraints that cannot be dropped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET y = 6 - y
WHERE x = 9
```

note:

if there are other values in column `y` for `x = 9` that don't need to be touched, don't forget to also add something like

```
AND y IN (1,5)
```

EDIT:

General formula for swapping any two numbers `a` and `b`  would be:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET col= (a+b) - col
WHERE col IN (a,b)
```

Comment: +1 for single query but only for 5 and 1, but it wont work of swap when it come to 2 and 4 and other

Comment: Well, it's 1+5 :) ... I don't know how you came with this two specific numbers, but swapping any two numbers (a & b) is (a+b) - number = other number. Not sure how much your actual data and requirement differs from example you have posted?

Comment: @Nenad, ty, I'm trying this now

Comment: Reverted from what I said. Excellent and simple solution! +1 Vote for Nenad Zivkovic.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you know the primary keys and they are contiguous:

```
UPDATE table SET y = 5 WHERE pk BETWEEN 7 AND 9;
UPDATE table SET y = 1 WHERE pk BETWEEN 10 AND 12;
```

Otherwise, I would select the concerned rows primary keys into a temporary tables:

```
SELECT pk INTO TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 FROM table WHERE x = 9 AND y = 1;
SELECT pk INTO TEMPORARY TABLE temp2 FROM table WHERE x = 9 AND y = 5;

UPDATE table AS t FROM temp1 SET y = 5 WHERE t.pk = temp1.pk
UPDATE table AS t FROM temp2 SET y = 1 WHERE t.pk = temp2.pk
```

Comment: PK's not guaranteed to be sequential. There are hundreds that need to be changed and it's common for the pk to be alternated. Thanks for the try ;)

Comment: What about the second solution?

Comment: See complete solution, although untested as I do not have a Postgres server at my disposal.